# Lua string.match... matching on a word, with optional punctuation at the end

Tags: lua, match

OK, I'm new to the Lua language.

I'm trying to run through some string matches, but if there's any punctuation after the word in my "dictionary" of sentences, the match isn't working.:

I had thought that adding a `%p?` would match on "zero or one punctuation mark", but that doesn't seem to be the case?

```
local string_that_matches = string.match(Dictionary[i], textsubmitted..'%p?')
```

Edit:  Adding a bit more info.  Here's the full routine:

Hmmm... well, I'm just checking to see if string_that_matches is nil... and if not, then add it to a new array of matches, since we're looping through about 50 items here:

```
local dictSize = table.maxn(Dictionary)
matches = {} -- new array to hold matches

for i=1,dictSize do -- Loop through dictionary items
    local string_that_matches = string.match(Dictionary[i],textsubmitted..'%p?')
    if string_that_matches ~= nil then
        table.insert(matches, Dictionary[i]) 
    end
end
return matches
```

Comment: Can you add examples of what's not working (and your expected result)?

Comment: Sure!   Dictionary[i] = "Good night, boys and girls."
textsubmitted = "night"

Doesn't result in a match.

Comment: I posted an answer, but this particular example matches for me as expected. Can you update the questions with examples that don't match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All these combinations match for me as expected:

```
string.match("Good night, boys and girls.", "night")
```

returns `night` and

```
string.match("Good night, boys and girls.", "night%p?")
```

returns `night,`.

If you want the match to not include the (optional) punctuation, then wrap your `textsubmitted` into parentheses:

```
string.match("Good night, boys and girls.", "(night)%p?")
```

This will return `night`.

Here is a full example you can experiment with:

```
local Dictionary = {"Good night, boys and girls."}

function trymatch(textsubmitted)
  local dictSize = table.maxn(Dictionary)
  matches = {} -- new array to hold matches

  for i=1,dictSize do -- Loop through dictionary items
    local string_that_matches = string.match(Dictionary[i],textsubmitted..'%p?')
    if string_that_matches ~= nil then
      table.insert(matches, Dictionary[i]) 
    end
  end
  return matches
end

print(trymatch("Good")[1])
print(trymatch("night")[1])
print(trymatch("boys")[1])
print(trymatch("nothing")[1])
```

This as expected prints:

```
Good night, boys and girls.
Good night, boys and girls.
Good night, boys and girls.
nil
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it that way. Will get back to you in a few minutes.

Comment: Well, I can match on 'boys', but I can't seem to match on 'Good' either.  Strange.

Comment: Matches `Good` for me as well; I added a full example.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Apparently, the game Warhammer Online has (yes, there's still a single server out there) its own data type called a 'wstring'.  I'm not exactly sure if that is in play here.  But I'm currently experimenting along those lines and seem to be making a bit of headway.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, it turns out, it had nothing to do with that Wstring stuff.

I don't know why that didn't work, but I used this as a work-around:

 `local this_dict_string = Dictionary[i]:gsub("([\.,;\-!\?\(\)])", " ");
        local string_that_matches = string.match(this_dict_string, textsubmitted) `